# Is ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor ok for doing multiple tasks at same time?

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

The docs for `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` says that -
Tasks scheduled for exactly the same execution time are enabled in first-in-first-out (FIFO) order of submission.

Does this mean that the tasks which SHOULD be done at the same time are never done at the same time. Instead they are executed in FIFO order ?

If that is true then which class do I use which is better than `Timer` and also does not have this FIFO problem ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor works is there is a single "scheduling" or master thread which checks for tasks to execute.

If it finds a task, it delegates it to a "worker" thread from the pool.

If multiple tasks are ready to be executed, they are "kicked off" one at a time, though once "kicked off", subsequent processing is concurrent, per Java's definition.

If you have two tasks that are both scheduled through the executor for the same time, the order in which they complete could vary from run to run and unless you put in specific controls such as locks, waits, etc... to handle this, it's up to java's thread scheduling (how java allots time to threads on a core) to determine how and when what gets processed.  Please note that setting up such locks, waits, etc... is a deceptively complex task prone to race conditions leading to unexpected deadlocks, live locks, etc...

Comment: Thanks. Where can I get some good tutorials on ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor?

I really needed an explanation on how these things work, instead of just API docs. Thanks to you, I have a better understanding of the purpose of each class. :)

Comment: Well, I'd suggest you first go back and consider what your requirements are in terms of concurrency.  When you submit something to a thread pool, the mindset is "It'll get done, pretty close to when I want it".  If you need several runnables executing in lockstep, note that this is a generally difficult to meet requirement and consider loosening this up if possible.  If you'd like to post some details I'd be happy to help.  A good place to start learning more about what java has is here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Comment: Please tell me what this means - you need several runnables executing in lockstep. If I know the meaning, then I can tell you if it is my requirement. Thanks.

Comment: Do you actually need several tasks happening in unison or if they are milliseconds to seconds out of syn is that fine?

Comment: How big can the difference in seconds be ? My use case - I want to turn 20-30 bulbs on, ideally all at the same time. A difference of milliseconds is ok. But, a difference of more than 2-3 seconds is unacceptable. Can I still use ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor ?

Comment: How long does it take to turn on an individual bulb?  I'd suggest trying with a ScheduledThreadPool and experimenting.  You can configure size of thread pool which gives you some leeway but as others have mentioned, the hardware you're using starts to come into play.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the size of your thread pool.  If you schedule 1000 tasks to fire at midnight, and you only have 25 threads, then only 25 can be executed initially, while the rest must wait for available threads.  FIFO here refers to the order in which the executor will hand tasks off to the execution threads.

Comment: Ok, so number of threads should be >= number of tasks? ">" is included for a safety margin in case we don't know how many tasks might have to be done at a certain time.

Comment: @Time: Do the tasks actually need to happen concurrently?  It might help if you can explain the requirements driving this.

Comment: As other answers have pointed out, the scheduled time is the time at which a task will be submitted to the execution pool.  It's a design decision how many threads you want, recall that true simultaneous execution requires parallel execution, which is limited by your hardware's cores.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the docs talk about "enabling" the tasks and that we are talking about a *threadpool* executor. :-)

That means the tasks will wait until the designated time, then they are treated as if put into a normal ThreadPoolExecutor. If there are enough threads available in the pool all these tasks will be run in parallel.

Only if you have more tasks becoming active than available threads in the pool some tasks will have to wait.